# curious exception in Visual C++ 10 at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, runtime-error

Today I got really strange exception at runtime. I tried to debug step by step, but the exception occurs before `main()` is called.

So I removed every include and the whole code (commented it), and added an empty `main()` function.

And again, after compiling it occurs. Maybe a project configuration bug?

BTW: after the exception, VC10 Debugger goes to strlen.asm and says empty pointer.

The VS10 solution got 2 projects the second works really well, and the first did too, but after I compiled the second project, it stopped working.

The Projects have the same Output of the binaries, but they got an extra output folder for obj etc.. files, for each Project.

So, whats going on there?

Comment: got any global variables? their c'tor may cause exception

Comment: please leave out the WTFs next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is most likely part of the initialization of a global or static object which then calls `strlen` with a null pointer. Do you have any globals in any .cpp? Or any statics in some classes?

Note that, even if you remove everything from the main.cpp, the other .cpp files will still be compiled and cause the error.

Comment: thank you very much, I got it, I had a static std::string in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Without any details it's hard to say anything precise, so I can only share advice based on two similar experiences I had. It wasn't in Visual Studio, but you might happen to have the same problem.

1. You might need a dynamically loaded component (dll, ocx etc.) that is not in the path where you run the debug version from.
2. You might have misbehaving global initializations